# ClassCastException for no reason?

Tags: java, class, casting

I'm getting a ClassCastException for seemingly no reason. Let me explain the structure of my code:
AbilityModifier is an abstract class
ProjectileModifier is an abstract class which extends AbilityModifier
NoGravity is a class which extends ProjectileModifier

AbilityModifier has a custom ClassLoader that I use to find all ability modifiers. This way I don't have the register them manually. However, to register them automatically, I need to cast them and add them to a List. When I cast it, it throws a ClassCastException saying that redempt.divinity.ability.modifier.modifiers.NoGravity cannot be cast to redempt.divinity.ability. I've done a test, and everything works with no exceptions:

```
package redempt.test;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
        Class<?> clazz = C.class;
        Object o = clazz.newInstance();
        A a = A.class.cast(o);
        System.out.println("Finished!");
    }
}
class A {
    public A() {

    }
}
class B extends A {
    public B() {

    }
}
class C extends B {
    public C() {

    }
}
```

So that works, but for some reason, my other code does not. Let me give you all the classes involved:

AbilityModifier:

```
package redempt.divinity.ability.modifier;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.reflect.Modifier;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLClassLoader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.jar.JarEntry;
import java.util.jar.JarFile;
import org.bukkit.Material;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import redempt.divinity.Main;
import redempt.divinity.ability.AbilityType;

public abstract class AbilityModifier {
    public static Set<AbilityModifier> modifiers = new HashSet<AbilityModifier>();
    public abstract void onUse(Player player);
    public abstract String getName();
    public abstract Material getRepresentation();
    public abstract AbilityType getType();
    public static void registerAll() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException, URISyntaxException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
        File file = new File(Main.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().toURI());
        JarFile jar = new JarFile(file);
        file.toURI().toURL();
        URL[] urls = {file.toURI().toURL()};
        List<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
        URLClassLoader loader = URLClassLoader.newInstance(urls, ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader());
        Enumeration<JarEntry> entries = jar.entries();
        while (entries.hasMoreElements()) {
            JarEntry entry = entries.nextElement();
            String name = entry.getName().replace("/", ".");
            if (name.endsWith(".class")) {
                try {
                    Class<?> clazz = loader.loadClass(name.replaceAll("\\.class$", ""));
                    System.out.println("Loading class: " + clazz.getSimpleName());
                    System.out.println(isSubclass(clazz));
                    if (isSubclass(clazz) && !Modifier.isAbstract(clazz.getModifiers())) {
                        names.add(clazz.getSimpleName());
                        AbilityModifier modifier = AbilityModifier.class.cast(clazz.newInstance());
                    }
                } catch (NoClassDefFoundError e) {
                    System.out.println("Unable to load class: " + name);
                }
            }
        }
        loader.close();
        jar.close();
        System.out.println(Main.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().toURI().toURL().getPath());
        System.out.println("All ability modifiers found:");
        for (String name : names) {
            System.out.println(name);
        }
    }
    public static void register(Class<? extends AbilityModifier> clazz) {

    }
    private static boolean isSubclass(Class<?> clazz) {
        if (clazz.getSuperclass().equals(Object.class)) {
            return false;
        }
        return clazz.getSuperclass().getName().equals(AbilityModifier.class.getName()) ? true : isSubclass(clazz.getSuperclass());
    }
}
```

ProjectileModifier:

```
package redempt.divinity.ability.modifier;

import org.bukkit.entity.Entity;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.event.entity.EntityDamageByEntityEvent;
import redempt.divinity.ability.Ability;

public abstract class ProjectileModifier extends AbilityModifier {
    public abstract void onUse(Player player, Entity projectile);
    @Override
    public void onUse(Player player) {
    }
    public abstract void onHit(Ability item, int level, EntityDamageByEntityEvent event);
    public abstract void onTick(Entity projectile);
}
```

NoGravity:

```
package redempt.divinity.ability.modifier.modifiers;

import org.bukkit.Location;
import org.bukkit.Material;
import org.bukkit.entity.Entity;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.event.entity.EntityDamageByEntityEvent;
import org.bukkit.util.Vector;
import redempt.divinity.ability.Ability;
import redempt.divinity.ability.AbilityType;
import redempt.divinity.ability.modifier.ProjectileModifier;

public class NoGravity extends ProjectileModifier {
    Vector vector;
    Location lastpos;
    @Override
    public void onUse(Player player, Entity projectile) {
        vector = player.getLocation().getDirection().normalize();
        lastpos = projectile.getLocation().clone();
    }
    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "No gravity";
    }
    @Override
    public Material getRepresentation() {
        return Material.FEATHER;
    }
    @Override
    public AbilityType getType() {
        return AbilityType.PROJECTILE;
    }
    @Override
    public void onHit(Ability item, int level, EntityDamageByEntityEvent event) {
    }
    @Override
    public void onTick(Entity entity) {
        lastpos.add(vector);
        if (lastpos.getBlock().getType().equals(Material.AIR)) {
            entity.setVelocity(vector);
        }
        lastpos = entity.getLocation().clone();
    }
    public NoGravity() {
    }
}
```

Exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: redempt.divinity.ability.modifier.modifiers.NoGravity cannot be cast to redempt.divinity.ability.modifier.AbilityModifier
        at redempt.divinity.ability.modifier.AbilityModifier.registerAll(AbilityModifier.java:47) ~[?:?]
        at redempt.divinity.Main.onEnable(Main.java:30) ~[?:?]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin.setEnabled(JavaPlugin.java:292) ~[spigot-1.9.jar:git-Spigot-f04e043-52c7fc0]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader.enablePlugin(JavaPluginLoader.java:340) [spigot-1.9.jar:git-Spigot-f04e043-52c7fc0]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.enablePlugin(SimplePluginManager.java:405) [spigot-1.9.jar:git-Spigot-f04e043-52c7fc0]
        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_9_R1.CraftServer.loadPlugin(CraftServer.java:361) [spigot-1.9.jar:git-Spigot-f04e043-52c7fc0]
        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_9_R1.CraftServer.enablePlugins(CraftServer.java:321) [spigot-1.9.jar:git-Spigot-f04e043-52c7fc0]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_9_R1.MinecraftServer.t(MinecraftServer.java:411) [spigot-1.9.jar:git-Spigot-f04e043-52c7fc0]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_9_R1.MinecraftServer.l(MinecraftServer.java:376) [spigot-1.9.jar:git-Spigot-f04e043-52c7fc0]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_9_R1.MinecraftServer.a(MinecraftServer.java:331) [spigot-1.9.jar:git-Spigot-f04e043-52c7fc0]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_9_R1.DedicatedServer.init(DedicatedServer.java:269) [spigot-1.9.jar:git-Spigot-f04e043-52c7fc0]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_9_R1.MinecraftServer.run(MinecraftServer.java:527) [spigot-1.9.jar:git-Spigot-f04e043-52c7fc0]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_65]
```

Comment: Please post the stacktrace of the exception and point out in your code where it occurs.

Comment: Could you please add the full exception message?

Comment: Sure, give me a minute

Comment: Ok, I addded the exception to the question.

Comment: The stacktrace says you are trying to cast a NoGravity object to AbilityModifier. NoGravity and AbilityModifier are sharing a parent child relationship, but casting the subclass object to superclass is wrong. You can absolutely have a superclass reference variable to store the subclass object, but cannot cast the subclass object to superclass. Please let me know if I understood your question wrong.

Comment: Oh, I get what you mean. But how do I cast it from Object to something else? I need it in a variable that sees it as an AbilityModifier, and I don't know how to get it there. Do I cast the class to Class<? extends AbilityModifier>?

Comment: @Manish You are wrong. It is possible to cast a subclass to (one of) its superclasses, it is just (usually) unnecessary. The problem is more likely one of classloaders and that the used `AbilityModifier` class was loaded by a different classloader than `NoGravity` and its (grand)parent `AbilityModifier` (so there are two different class instances of `AbilityModifier`(!)).

Comment: But it uses System.getClassLoader(), so I don't think that's true

Comment: @ViperLordX That depends on which class loader loaded `AbilityModifier`. You might be better off by using the classloader that loaded `AbilityModifier` (eg `AbilityModifier.class.getClassLoader()`. That said, I don't regularly muck around with class loaders, so I might be a bit off here.

Comment: Ok, that fixed it! Why don't you post that as an answer and I'll accept it

Comment: @MarkRotteveel - Yeah, you are right about that. It is unnecessary but not an error. Thanks to let me know about that and also about the classloader issue.

Comment: Are you gonna post it as an answer?

Comment: I will in a minute or so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the class `NoGravity` is loaded through a different classloader than that the `AbilityModifier` class you reference in your code. As a result, `NoGravity` has a different class instance of `AbilityModifier` as its grandparent, so casting won't work.

To fix this, you need to use the same classloader as the one that loaded the `AbilityModifier` in your code.

You need to change:

```
URLClassLoader loader = URLClassLoader.newInstance(urls,
    ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader());
```

To

```
URLClassLoader loader = URLClassLoader.newInstance(urls,
    AbilityModifier.class.getClassLoader());
```

For more details, see [Understanding Java class loading](https://blogs.oracle.com/sundararajan/entry/understanding_java_class_loading):

> At runtime, a Java class is uniquely identified by the pair - the fully qualified name of the class and the defining loader that loaded it. If the same named (i.e., same fully qualified name) class is defined by two different loaders, these classes are different - even if the .class bytes are same and loaded from the same location (URL).

Answer (score 0):

Since C is an indirect subclass of A, in this case NoGravity of AbilityModifier, each instance of NoGravity is an instance of AbilityModifier. However, the clazz.newInstance() method returns an Object which must be casted. I suggest you try to assign an AbilityModifier this object after casting it to NoGravity, like this:

`AbilityModifier a = (NoGravity) clazz.newInstance();`

EDIT, another thing you can try is the following:

```
if (AbilityModifier.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz)) {
    AbilityModifier instance = ((Class<AbilityModifier>) clazz).newInstance();
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Slightly off topic, as far as I'm aware you can scrap your whole isSubclass() method and replace it with `AbilityModifier.class.isAssignableFrom(loadedClass);`

Answer (score -4):

Just Build->Clean your project.

Comment: What do you mean, clean my project?

Comment: How will cleaning the project help in resolving ClassCastException? This is not ClassNotFoundException, where you can expect such anomalies or missing libraries in project.

Comment: just go to build option in android studio toolbar and try to Clean and then Rebuild and then run your project